# How do I change the format of a single cell in a pandas data frame?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, format, jupyter-notebook

My Data frame has summary of values for different types of metrics. They are all floats, but I need the budget to show up with a '$' and the two bottom rows as % instead of decimal.  I have provided screen shots as I do not know how to else to properly display my jupyter notebook code in stackoverflow.

[image]

I tried using iLoc .map .format but it did not work.

[image]

```
district_summary.iloc[[6,1].map('{:,%.2f}'.format)]
```

> ```
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
> <ipython-input-40-a2f927a382d3> in <module>
> ----> 1 district_summary.iloc[[6,1].map('{:,%.2f}'.format)]
>
> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'map'
> ```

I need the budget to show with a preceeding $ and with no decimal points, and the two percentages at the bottom 2 rows to show up as %xx.xx

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to get it to work, however, better solutions are out there. The df is converted to a string so that all datatypes within the cells remain consistent. i.e. a '%' or '$' cannot be read as a float.

```
pd.set_option('mode.chained_assignment', None)
df['Value'][6:8] = df['Value'][6:8]*100
df = df.applymap(str)
df['Value'][2] = '$' + df['Value'][2]
df['Value'][:3] = df['Value'][:3] + '0'
df['Value'][6:8] = '%'+ df['Value'][6:8] + '0'
```

String Dataframe Result:
 [image]

Comment: Thank you for the solution recommendation and alternative approach.